# How to determine whether an object is contained by an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array `arr1`, which contains all objects.

```
var arr1 = [{name:"haha1"},{name:"haha2"}]
```

I also have an object.

```
var a1 = {name:"haha1"};
```

So, how do I determine whether `a1` is equal to any of the objects in `arr1`? I tried `==` but it doesn't check if the properties of the objects are equal.

Comment: You want to check if an object with values identical to that of a1 exists in the array?

Comment: You need to loop through the array, and check if the `name` of each object is equal to the `name` of `a1`.

Comment: Hi, your question is a bit confusing. The `arr1` is an array of objects and the `a1` is an object. What do you want? Do you want to see if `a1` is contained in `arr1`, meaning that there is an object with the same value for the name property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the array, and compare each object in it to `a1`.

```js
var arr1 = [{name:"haha1"},{name:"haha2"}]
var a1 = {name:"haha1"};

function objectsEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  var equal = obj1.name === obj2.name;
  return equal;
}

var i;

for(i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if(objectsEqual(a1, arr1[i])) {
    console.log('a1 is equal to object at index ' + i);
  }
}
```

I created a function to check for equality, because you may have more properties to check in your real code. So, you can check them all in that function, and re-use that function in other places, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `underscore` library.

```
var arr1 = [{name:"haha1"},{name:"haha2"}]
var a1 = {name:"haha1"};

var isContainsObj = function  (arr, obj) {
    return _.where(arr1, a1).length > 0
}

console.log(isContainsObj(arr1, a1)) //true
```